Testing a form with vue utils on Vue.js 3 - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
Essentially, I'm trying to test an emitted event's result on a form. However, when I launch my test, this error is returned:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value').

It occurs when my code tries to access any html part of the form. (Ex. if(NAME_INPUT.value == '')
Usually, this error is lauched when the HTMLElement that is accessed is null, so the value property doesnt exist. However, outside my tests, this HTMLElement is acccessed properly and everything runs fine.
Here is the form component:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import type Ship from '../scripts/ship'

const props = defineProps<{ 
    ships: Ship[]
}>()

    let nameError = ref<string>("");
    let shipError = ref<string>("");
    const NAME_INPUT : HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById("inputCharacterName") as HTMLInputElement;
    const SHIP_SELECT : HTMLSelectElement = document.getElementById("spaceship") as HTMLSelectElement;

    const selectedShip = defineModel('selectedShip')
    const emit = defineEmits(['playGame'])
    
    function onSubmit(this: any){
        let isFormValid : boolean = true;

        if(NAME_INPUT.value == ''){
            nameError.value = "Votre nom ne doit pas être vide"
            isFormValid = false;
        } else { nameError.value = '' }

        if(SHIP_SELECT.value == 'null') {
            shipError.value = "Choisissez un vaisseau"
            isFormValid = false;
        }  else { shipError.value = "" }
        
        if(isFormValid){
            let username = NAME_INPUT.value
            let shipName = this.selectedShip
            emit('playGame', username, shipName)
    }
}
</script>
<template>
    <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();" id="playerCreation" class="needs-validation">
      <div class="mx-3 form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="inputCharacterName">Nom du personnage</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCharacterName" placeholder="Nom du personnage">
        <button v-if="nameError !=''" id="error" class="active btn btn-danger col-12">{{ nameError }}</button>
      </div>
      <div class="mx-3 form-group">
        <label class="form-label" for="spaceship">Vaisseau</label>
        <select v-model="selectedShip" id="spaceship" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
          <option selected value="null">Choisir votre VAISSEAU</option>
          <option v-for="ship in ships" :value="ship.name">{{ ship.name }}</option>
          
        </select>
        <button v-if="shipError !=''" id="shipError" class="active btn btn-danger col-12">{{ shipError }}</button>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center mt-3">
        <button id="submitButton" type="submit" @click="onSubmit()" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Jouer</button>
      </div>
    </form>
</template>

And here is the Test file :
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import PlayerForm from '../PlayerForm.vue'
import { shipMockArray, shipMockName } from './shipMock'

describe('PlayerForm.vue', () => {

  it('Doit pouvoir naviguer sur la page du formulaire du jeu', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(PlayerForm, {
      props: {
        ships : shipMockArray
      }
    })

    await wrapper.find('#inputCharacterName').setValue('name')
    await wrapper.find('#spaceship').setValue('Ship')

    const submit = await wrapper.find('#submitButton');
    await submit.trigger('click')

    const submitEvent = wrapper.emitted();
    expect(submitEvent).toHaveProperty('playGame')
    expect(submitEvent).toEqual(['name','ship'])

  })
})

I've looked for similar problems, with no avail. I've also tried commenting my validation, but every access to html (.value) has caused the error.
